# Toggling through multiple options in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, task

I am creating a small todo app to learn Angular. I am stuck in one place. My task will be listed as list of links. Each time user clicks on it its status should change. So when a user
clicks on a task its status becomes, `doing`. Then in next click it become `done`. And one click makes it `later`. This should also reflect be stored back to the `$scope` from where this loaded. I have no idea, what will be the best way to do this in Angular.

Right now I have `$scope.tasks` storing all the tasks and  `$scope.tasks.$status` is holding the available stasuses.

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.tasks = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Do something.', status: 'doing'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Undo that thing.', status: 'done'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Redo it again.', status: 'started'},
    {id: 4, text: 'Responsive', status:'later'}
  ];

  $scope.tasks = {
    status: ['doing','done', 'later' ]
  };

 $scope.clicked = function() {

  //some logic.        

 };

}
```

Below is the html.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" class"container">
 <div ng-repeat="task in tasks" >
    <li>
       <a href="#"  ng-click="clicked()" id="{{task.id}}">
        {{task.text}} - {{task.status}}
       <a/>
    </li>
 </div>

</div>
```

Is whatever I done so far correct? What is the best approach to toggle through the options? Is there any functions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're tons of solutions depending on what you want to do with this next. The simplest one seems to be:

```
$scope.clicked = function(task){
  task.status = nextStatus(task.status);
};
function nextStatus(st){
  return $scope.statuses[$scope.statuses.indexOf(st) + 1];
}
```

Note that you also should pass task to the function:

```
<a ng-click='clicked(task)'>
```